# mutating object as singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am not sure, if anyone has asked this question before (If so apologies).

code copied from wikipedia.

```
public class Singleton {
   private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }
}
```

How it is thread safe? is it(only) because there is no mutating state in this class?

what happens if I modify it like this

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private FancyClass obj1;
    private FancyClass obj2;

    //feel free to imagine all the getters and setters for obj1 and obj2,
    // like getObj1() and so forth

    //tricky method
    public void doSomething() {
      obj1.destroyEnemy();
      obj2.destroyFriend();
    }

    private Singleton() {
       obj1 = null;
       obj2 = null;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return instance;
    }
}
```

I have no interest in design-patterns discussion, this is the kind of code, I am supposed to maintain. is the above 'singleton' thread safe, assuming that FancyClass is java standard library class.

Comment: Since you are making your constructor private it will never be called. So declaring it null there makes no sense. Anyway instance variables are automatically assigned default values.

Comment: @AniketThakur Yeah, That is super-dumb(initiializing in constructor with null). I was just rewriting an existing class without specifics.

Comment: Note, bunging a `synchronized` in wont make operations that require multiple method calls thread-safe. A `synchronized` "get" method is usually pointless. (ObComment: Mutable statics are a really bad idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the first example is safe only because there is no mutable state.

In the second example, the singleton isn't doing anything to make it threadsafe, whether it's safe depends on if `FancyClass` is threadsafe. Putting `synchronized` on the `doSomething` method would make it threadsafe.

Introducing getters and setters for `obj1` and `obj2` would also have the potential to create problems, those would have to be synchronized on the same lock as the `doSomething` method, and you would need locking even if `FancyClass` is threadsafe, because if different threads are changing things then those changes need to be made visible across threads.

Comment: Ok, FancyClass is thread safe according to docs. (part of JDK)

Answer (score 3):

The first code guarantees that *all* threads that call `getInstance()` get a reference to the same instance of `Singleton`.

For your implementation (second example), the same is true for `obj1` and `obj2`, because they're created while the class itself is created and class creation is thread safe (can't be created twice/"in parallel" within the same classloader).

The `doSomething()` method is not thread safe. Make it `synchronized` if you need an atomic operation.

Comment: I assume same would be true with, getters and setters of obj1 and obj2, I need to make them synchronized as well?

Comment: @fedvasu If you only set or get the objects, then synchronization is not necessary. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1351271/105224

Answer (score 1):

The Singleton pattern is not designed to be Thread Safe at all, just to be unique and forbidding creation of additional instances. The only part that is thread safe in you code is the Singleton instantiation `private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();` as it's invoked one time a class loading time.

But effectively, if there's no members in your class modified by a method invked concurently by external systems, your Singleton will be/stay ThreadSafe

Answer (score 0):

About your code -
Since you are making your constructor private it will never be called. So declaring it null there makes no sense. Anyway instance variables are automatically assigned default values.

First of all the 1st code

```
   public class Singleton {
   private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }
}
```

is called Early initialization unlike lazy initialization in which you create instance only when needed. To make it thread safe you need to do the following

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton singleInstance;
    private Singleton() {}
  public static Singleton getSingleInstance() {
    if (singleInstance == null) {
      synchronized (Singleton.class) {
        if (singleInstance == null) {
          singleInstance = new Singleton();
        }
      }
    }
    return singleInstance;
  }
```

Example is of lazy initialization but the concept remains the same.

Comment: You forgot set it as volatile it should be:  private static volatile Singleton singleInstance = null;

Comment: Why do you need to if statements checking the same thing. I'm assuming that's a mistake?

Comment: @AndrewMartin No it is not a mistake. It is called double locking mechanism. Here is the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: @AniketThakur: Thanks - never seen that before. Will read up on it.

Comment: @AndresL Yes problems might arise during thread scheduling. So it is good practice to declare it as volatile as well. Thanks for pointing it out.