# How to replace a non-synchronized concurrent list or array atomically

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, readwritelock, copyonwritearraylist

I have a `List` read (iterated through) many times and by multiple threads but updated rarely (reads are more than 50,000 times more numerous). EDIT: in fact, an array would suffice in this case, instead of a List.

When the list is updated, it's simply replaced with a different version (there are no `add()` or `remove()` calls).

A [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) avoid the disadvantages of a synchronized list but I'm not sure that setting the list to the new value is atomic. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351223/thread-safe-setting-of-a-variable-java) question as well.

To show some code. Consider the following as an attribute of a singleton Spring bean.

```
List<MyObject> myList; //the list read many times and concurrently. 

//called by many threads
public void doStuff(){           
     for (MyObject mo : myList){
         //do something
     }
}       

//called rarely. It's synchronized to prevent concurrent updates
//but my question is about thread-safety with regards to readers
public synchronized void updateList(List<MyObject> newList){  // newList is a CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); 
    myList = myNewList;  //is this following statement executed atomically and thread-safe for readers?
}
```

Do I need to use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) for achieve a thread-safe set?

Comment: I think it would suffice to make the list `volatile`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for ReadWriteLock depends what you need to achieve.
If you want to ensure that reference is updated atomically you can use [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (or in your case enough to mark this reference as volatile), however if your goal is that updater thread should wait until all reading threads finish iterating over old list before updating the reference then ReadWriteLock is the way to go.

Comment: That's a good point about waiting for readers to finish. In my case, the list is short (<10 items) so with the projected load there will be a moment when all iterations are done and "it's quiet". This raises the interesting question about what to do if the list is long enough and the arrival rate high enough that new readers start iterating while others are finished, so there's always at least one iteration going on.

Comment: As I wrote it depends on use case. If you are fine that some threads are iterating over old list then go with volatile, however I can imagine several use cases when you want to be sure that once updated no one is using old list.